# Frontend con Json

Tags: html, html5, json, web

Soy novato en el mundo web ( Html5) , estoy dando mis primeros pasos. Pido mis disculpas y por favor su comprensión.

Necesito hacer una página web con front end con las siguientes características:

_No hay necesidad de desarrollar backend (JAVA, PHP,Etc), usted puede usar datos fijos en un JSON para la carga inicial y mantener los demás datos en memoria.

Nunca he trabajado con Json, me puede orientar por favor?
Supongo que es un archivo pero., ¿como me comunico con el archivo?

Me imagino que el archivo quede alojado en, ejemplo: C:\miarquivo.json

¿Como realizo el CRUD ( Crear, Leer, Actualizar, Borrar)?

Comment: Simplemente has peticiones AJAX al archivo json local. Esto te retornará su contenido y a partir de allí obtienes los datos que se te piden para los tests.

Answer (score 0):

JSON o JavaScript Object Notation es un formato estandarizado basado en la sucesión de pares clave valor. ¿Qué significa esto? Que existe una lista de elementos en que cada uno de ellos tiene un valor y un nombre.

El formato estándar es este:

```
{
    clave: valor
}
```

Como puedes ver varios valores, se separan mediante comas simples:

```
{
    clave1: valor1,
    clave2: valor2
}
```

Sabiendo que un objeto `JSON` puede contener, a su vez, elementos con el mismo formato. Pongamos un ejemplo real.

```
const persona = {
    nombre: 'Juan',
    edad: 23,
    ciudad = {
        nombre: 'Madrid',
        país: 'España'
    }
}
```

Recibiendo los datos de un back-end, entiendo que los recibirás en formato `JSON` directamente, si necesitases parsearlos de un `String` o formato texto necesitarías utilizar la función de JavaScript `JSON.parse`. Te pongo otro ejemplo:

```
const persona = "{nombre: 'Juan', edad: 23, ciudad = {nombre: 'Madrid', país: 'España'}}"

const persona_json = JSON.parse(persona);
```

Finalmente, JavaScript tine una facilidad nativa para trabajar con objetos de tipo JSON, por lo que para obtener tales datos necesitas llamarlos simplemente mediante un punto seguido de su nombre. Tan sencillo como

```
alert("Hola " + persona.nombre);
```

Si quieres buscar en profundidad, es tan sencillo como anidar puntos:

```
alert("Hola " + persona.nombre + ", " + persona.ciudad.nombre + " es una ciudad preciosa);
```

Creo que con esto tienes lo básico para trabajar con un JSON. Para cargarlo deberías de llamar al Servidor ya que no debería de estar alojado en el local de cada cliente.

Respecto a la pregunta del CRUD, me parece excesivamente genérica como para ser respondida punto por punto. Si ya existe un back-end, la parte que consiste en la modificación, el alta y la eliminación de datos estará mantenida, por lo que tu trabajo es hacer un formulario de alta, otro de modificación y una vista en la que se puedan ver y seleccionar para modificar y eliminar todos los datos de tal JSON.

Comment: Como indique arriba:No hay necesidad de desarrollar backend (JAVA, PHP,Etc), usted puede usar datos fijos en un JSON para la carga inicial y mantener los demás datos en memoria.

Estructura del objeto persona
{
“nome”: “Fulano”,
“documento”: “123456”,
“telefone”: “99123 4567”
}

Estrutura del check in
{
“pessoa”: objPessoa,
“dataEntrada”: “2018-03-14T08:00:00”,
“dataSaida”: “2018-03-16T10:17:00”,
“adicionalVeiculo”: true/false
}

Comment: Ya tenía en cuenta que no ibas a desarrollar backend, mi idea era explicarte el concepto para que puedas trabajar con él. ¿Cuál es la pregunta ahora?

Comment: Hola, nuevamente...mis disculpas!!!
Estoy muy perdido.... me dijeron que se usa la técnica de " http con mock ".
Todo lo que es Front end ya lo hice.
No se si entendi mal, pero me dijeron que deberia crear el Json en la carpeta del proyecto.
Pero no se como hacer eso del crud.
Me podrias orientar un poco mas por favor? Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que todo es que puedes editar y modificar un json sin necesidad de un servidor, sin embargo el inconveniente es que estos datos no se modificarán ni persistiran los cambios si no hay un proceso de servidor involucrado.

Puedes crear un archivo json en una carpeta

[image: Carpeta con archivo json]

puedes leer el archivo de esta manera con jquery ("Puede hacerse con muchas otras herramientas en javascript incluso con javascript nativo")

```
 $.getJSON("json/calendar_dates.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //Mostrara el json en la consola de javascript
  });
```

Una vez tengas el json en el navegador puedes moldearlo y agregarle nuevos elementos así como eliminarlos para esto toca usar procesos que involucren operaciones de objetos en javascript for ejemplo:

```
data.push({event:"Soy un nuevo evento"});
```

Agregar un nuevo elemento a lista de objetos json traidas desde el archivo.

```
index = data.indexOf(event);
data.splice(index, 1);
```

Eliminaria un elemento de la lista de objetos json.